# string iterator not decrementable

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I have an issue with **string::iterator**. VS says **string iterator not decrementable**. My first project works fine with the same function **Is_Palindrom**

```
 #include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <valarray>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

string Is_Palindrom(string str)
{
    string::iterator iter = str.begin();

    transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), tolower);

    for (iter; iter != str.end(); iter++)
    {
        if (ispunct(*iter) || *iter == *" ")
        {
            str.erase(iter);
            iter--;
        }
    }

    return str;
}

void main()
{
    ostream_iterator<string, char>out(cout, "\n");
    string tmp;
    vector<string>str;

    while (getline(cin, tmp) && tmp != "quit")
        str.push_back(tmp);

    transform(str.begin(), str.end(), out, Is_Palindrom);
}
```

But if I load some words from a **.txt** and apply Is_Palindrome function it crashes, but if I change **string::iterator** to a simple loop with a **[ ]** access it works correct.
Here the problem code.

```
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <valarray>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::tolower;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;

string Is_Palindrom(string str);

int main()
{
    vector <string> wordlist;

    std::srand(std::time(0));

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("text.txt");
    if (fin.is_open() == false)
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't open file. Bye.\n"; // не удается открыть файл 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    string item;
    int count = 0;
    getline(fin, item, ' ');
    wordlist.push_back(item);
    transform(wordlist.begin(), wordlist.end(), wordlist.begin(), Is_Palindrom);

    while (fin) // до тех пор, пока нет ошибок ввода 
    {
        cout << count << " : " << wordlist[count] << endl;
        ++count;
        getline(fin, item, ' ');
        wordlist.push_back(item);
        transform(wordlist.begin(), wordlist.end(), wordlist.begin(), Is_Palindrom);
    }
    cout << "Done\n";
    fin.close();

    char play;
    cout << "Will you play a word game? <y/n> "; // запуск игры в слова 
    cin >> play;
    play = tolower(play);
    while (play == 'y')
    {
        string target = wordlist[std::rand() % wordlist.size()];
        int length = target.length();
        string attempt(length, '-');
        string badchars;
        int guesses = 6;
        cout << "Guess my secret word. It has " << length
            << " letters, and you guess\n"
            << "one letter at a time. You get " << guesses
            << " wrong guesses.\n";
        cout << "Your word: " << "attempt" << endl; // вывод слова
        while (guesses > 0 && attempt != target)
        {
            char letter;
            cout << "Guess a letter: ";
            cin >> letter;
            if (badchars.find(letter) != string::npos || attempt.find(letter) != string::npos)
            {
                cout << "You already guessed that. Try again.\n";
                continue;
            }
            int loc = target.find(letter);
            if (loc == string::npos)
            {
                cout << "Oh, bad guess !\n";
                --guesses;
                badchars += letter; // добавить к строке 
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Good guess!\n";
                attempt[loc] = letter;
                // Проверить, не появляется ли буква еще раз 
                loc = target.find(letter, loc + 1);
                while (loc != string::npos)
                {
                    attempt[loc] = letter;
                    loc = target.find(letter, loc + 1);
                }
            }
            cout << "Your word: " << attempt << endl;
            if (attempt != target)
            {
                if (badchars.length() > 0)
                    cout << "Bad choices: " << badchars << endl;
                cout << guesses << " bad guesses left\n";
            }
        }
        if (guesses > 0)
            cout << "That's right!\n";
        else
            cout << "Sorry, the word is " << target << " . \n";
        cout << "Will you play another? <y/n> ";
        cin >> play;
        play = tolower(play);
    }
    cout << "Bye\n";
    return 0;
}

string Is_Palindrom(string str)
{
    string::iterator iter = str.begin();

    //for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    for (iter; iter != str.end(); iter++)
    {
        //if (ispunct(str[i]) || str[i] == *" ")
        if (ispunct(*iter) || *iter == *" ")
        {
            //str.erase(i, 1);
            //i--;
            str.erase(iter, iter+1);
            if (iter == str.end())
                break;
            iter--;
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: After you call `erase` you invalidate the iterator, so you shouldn't be trying to increment or decrement it.

Comment: @ CoryKramer BUT first project works fine with all the same except loading from a .txt

Comment: [OT]:Instead of `*" "`, you may wrote `' '`.

Comment: `auto it = str.begin(); --it; ++it;` is incorrect whereas `int i = 0; --i; ++i;` is correct.

Comment: @  Jarod42 not an issue. I presented first version of my working code with `auto it = str.begin(); --it; ++it`  then I modified it to add fstream and it did not work.

Comment: Well my bad! It works fine if I use a `string::iterator` one time for the second time it crashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your code is

```
if (ispunct(*iter) || *iter == *" ")
{
    str.erase(iter);
    iter--;
}
```

First, if you want to check a character you should use `'` not `"`.  So your 
statement should be

```
if (ispunct(*iter) || *iter == ' ')
//or even better
if (ispunct(*iter) || isspace(*iter))
```

Secondly, you are using `erase()`.  When you call erase it invalidates all references and iterators to the current element to the end.  Since you are using the same iterator that you used to delete the element this is **[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**.  Just because it works in the first example doesn't mean it will work in another piece of code.  Luckily `erase()` returns an iterator to the element after the erased element.  We can capture that iterator and use that for the next iteration.  In order to do this, you need to change your for loop into a while loop like:

```
while(iter != str.end())
{
    if (ispunct(*iter) || isspace(*iter))
        iter = str.erase(iter);  // erase and don't increment as we are already on the next character
    else
        iter++; // increment since it was a valid character
}
```

Comment: Using the character-classification-functions with any arbitrary `char` is also wrong. Don't forget the cast to `unsigned char`!